# How to store the json response in an array and sort it

Tags: json, string, groovy, formatter

I want to store the values relationship id, relationshipType  in an array ,    sort and then print that array in Groovy.
I have this so far...

```
def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def result = slurper.parseText(reponse)

{"RecipientRelationships": [
      {
      "RelationshipId": "15",
      "RelationshipType": "Self"
   },
      {
      "RelationshipId": "1",
      "RelationshipType": "Mother"
   },
      {
      "RelationshipId": "2",
      "RelationshipType": "Father"
   },
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please add a tag for whatever programming language you want? Because I suspect `import json: print(json.loads(s))` is not the answer you seek

Comment: iam looking for solution in groovy

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def response = '''{"RecipientRelationships": [
        {
            "RelationshipId": "15",
            "RelationshipType": "Self"
        },
        {
            "RelationshipId": "1",
            "RelationshipType": "Mother"
        },
        {
            "RelationshipId": "2",
            "RelationshipType": "Father"
        }]
}'''
JsonSlurper slurper = new JsonSlurper()
Map result = slurper.parseText(response)
result.RecipientRelationships.sort {
    it.RelationshipId as Integer
}.each {
    println it
}
```

Comment: i need to use the results to compare it to the table values    id realtionships  
1 father
2 mother
31 sisterinlaw
23 son
24 daughter

Comment: thanks philBa the intent of keeping the parsed results of the response was so that i could use that to comapare against the result of query

Answer (score 0):

```
     i need to use the results to compare it to the table values    
     id realtionships   
     1  father
     2  mothera
     31 sisterinlaw
      23    son
    24  daughter

      i have already printed the results of the query like this
      inside a function()
    {
     query = "select id , relationships from table"
      return result
     result= db.rows(query)
     }

     now i need to compare the results of the table  with the response
```